# Why am I not getting a plot of my function?

Tags: plotting, functions

I consider the polynomial $f(c,x):=x^{c+1}-c^c-1$ and I want to plot the function $\frac{\rho_c}{1+\frac{\ln(c)}{c}}$, where $\rho_c$ is the largest positive real root of $f(c,x)$.

---

I tried the following:

First, I define the function f:

```
f[c_, x_] := x^(c + 1) - x^c - 1
```

The function $g$ detects the real roots and the function $g1$ the largest positive real root:

```
g[c_, x_] := NSolve[f[c, x], x, Reals]

g1[c_, x_] := Max[x /. g[c, x]]
```

Finally, I define the desired function of $c$:

```
g2[c_] := 1 + (ln[c]/c);

g3[c_] := g1[c, x]/g2[c]
```

This works, for example I get

```
g3[5]
```

> `1.2852/(1 + ln[5]/5)`

Now I tried to plot the function $g3$ as a function of $c$ for $2\leq c\leq 100$, by

```
Plot[g3, {c, 2, 10}]
```

and I also tried

```
Plot[g3[c], {c, 2, 10}]
```

but nothing happens, nothing is plotted (only the axes):

[image: plotting]

What am I doing wrong? Please note that I am a beginner.

Comment: Your TeX formula does not match your code (typo in one or the other).  I used the code in my answer, since $x^{c+1} - c^c - 1$ has an obvious maximal root.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for $ln$ is `Log` and `g3[c]=g3[c_]:=` is not the correct way for assignment.

```
f[c_, x_] := x^(c + 1) - x^c - 1

g[c_?NumericQ] := NSolve[f[c, x], x, Reals]

g1[c_] := Max[x /. g[c]]

g2[c_] := 1 + (Log[c]/c);

g3[c_] := g1[c]/g2[c]

g3[5]

Plot[g3[c], {c, 2, 1000}]
```

[image]

Comment: What was my mistake: Only that I did not use Log? Yeeah, seems to tend to 1 as $c\to\infty$.

Comment: @mathfemi See the edit. If this is answer you were looking for then accept it as an answer?

Comment: I' m wondering about the functiondefinition  `g[c_, x_] := NSolve[f[c, x], x, Reals]` : What is the meaning of parameter x on the left side?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann You are right, Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Since `g` uses a numeric technique, its definition should be restricted to numeric arguments, i.e., `g[c_?NumericQ] := NSolve[f[c, x], x, Reals]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thx dear for your valueable comment.